# Relation between total days, absent days, and bonus‽

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algorithms

We are doing the following exercise: [Bonuses](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5d68d05e7a60ba002b0053f6). The statement is:

```
John wants to give a total bonus of $851 to his three employees taking fairly into account their number of days of absence during last year. Employee A was absent 18 days, B 15 days, and C 12 days.

The more absences, the lower the bonus ...

How much should each employee receive? John thinks A receives $230, B $276, C $345.
Task:

Given an array arr (numbers of days of absence for each employee) and a number s (total bonus) the function bonus(arr, s) returns an array of the fair bonuses of all employees in the same order as their numbers of days of absences.

s and all elements of arrays are positive integers.
Examples:

bonus([18, 15, 12], 851) -> [230, 276, 345]

bonus([30, 27, 8, 14, 7], 34067) -> [2772, 3080, 10395, 5940, 11880]

Notes

    There are only integers in the kata so try not to use floats if it is possible with your language.
    See Example Test Cases for more examples.
    Please ask before translating: some translations are already written and published when/if the kata is approved.
    In the random tests the number of elements of arr can be big
```

We would need to be able to solve it by hand before programming the algorithm.

We have tried to use the rule of 3, as follows:

```
Bonus -> Days absent
851 = 0
230 = x

x = 851 / 230 = 3,7
```

This result is invalid because of it should be 18 days absent

Then we thought about a system of three ecuations as follows:

```
851-18 = x
851-15 = y
851-12 = z
```

And then we thought how do we express that we should take into account the days of the bonus of others, to find the bonus of the current person.

In addition, we thought it could be solved calculating first the relation between each person's absence days, as follows:

```
Being daysAbsents (arr) = [18,15,12] and bonus (s) = 851:

First, calculate the relation, or multiplier from all absent days and the total of days:

multiplier += 1.0/arr[i];

multiplier += 1/18= 0.055
multiplier += 1/18= 0.055 + 0.066 = 0.12
multiplier += 1/18= 0.12 + 0.088 = 0.205

Then, we would need a way to calculate the relation between the total bonus and each one of the ays absent.
```

How could we calculate the relation between the **multiplier** (which is itself the relation between all days and all absent days); and **total bonus**‽

We have read:

- https://www.smartickmethod.com/blog/math/rule-of-3/
- https://www.sparknotes.com/math/algebra2/systemsofthreeequations/section1/

Answer (score 2):

What you are dealing with here is called inverse variation. So use that $18x=15y=12z$ and solve the equation $x+\frac{18}{15}x+\frac{18}{12}x=851$. Do you see where multiplier $3.7$ is coming from?

Comment: Nice: 1 + 18/15 + 18/12 = 3.7.  x = 851 / 3.7.  Thanks!